# Stuck in "Concurrency In Practise" article no Listing 2.1. A Stateless Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency

From the book:

2.1.1. Example: A Stateless Servlet
In Chapter 1, we listed a number of frameworks that create threads and call your components from those threads, leaving you with the responsibility of making your components thread-safe. Very often, thread-safety requirements stem not from a decision to use threads directly but from a decision to use a facility like the Servlets framework. We're going to develop a simple examplea servlet-based factorization serviceand slowly extend it to add features while preserving its thread safety.

Listing 2.1 shows our simple factorization servlet. It unpacks the number to be factored from the servlet request, factors it, and packages the results into the servlet response.

And the code example

```
@ThreadSafe  
public class StatelessFactorizer implements Servlet { 
public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {  
    BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);  
    BigInteger[] factors = factor(i);   
    encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);  
        }  
    }
```

With nothing else provided, I tried to get things working by first writing simple servlet in eclipse using dynamic-web module which worked and then modified the servlet as said in the above example by the following code. But this time I am getting a **404 error**, how can I test my new `servlet` which now

```
implements servlet
```

instead

```
extends HttpServlet
```

Code that I tried:

```
package com.serialize;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Test1
 */
@WebServlet("/Test1")
public class Test1 implements Servlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Test1() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.print("test1");
    //  service(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
        BigInteger[] factors = factor(i);
        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        pw.print(factors);
       // encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
    }

    private BigInteger extractFromRequest(ServletRequest req) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String num = req.getParameter("factor");
        return BigInteger.valueOf(Long.parseLong(num));
    }

    private BigInteger[] factor(BigInteger i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long number = i.longValue();
        BigInteger[] ret = null ;
        for(long j=2,indx=0;j<number/2;j++)
        {
            while(number%j == 0)
            {
                ret[(int) indx++]=BigInteger.valueOf(j);
                number = number / j;
            }

        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How are you accessing to your servlet? I mean, which URL are you using?

Comment: I am accessing in browser, like http://localhost:8080/testapp/Test2

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside of the doGet method, not inside the service method.

Don't implement Servlet, but extend from HttpServlet class.

Your code should look similar the one from [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/httpservlet.html) tutorial